# Exchange 2010 won't deliver a message to a DistributionGroup-Universal

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2010

this is the situation:

messages sent to a DistributionGroup-Universal group are not delivered to the group members. The same message sent to the group + a directly member address is delivered just to that member. For example, here is a example with Get-MessageTrackingLog from a message:

> sent: external user
>
> to: group@mydomain.com[*member1, member2, member3, member4*], member1@mydomain.com

```
MessageId       : <0001>
EventId         : RECEIVE
Timestamp       : 14.12.2016 19:03:47
Recipients      : member1@mydomain.com, group@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus :

MessageId       : <0001>
EventId         : EXPAND
Timestamp       : 14.12.2016 19:03:47
Recipients      : {member1@mydomain.com, member2@mydomain.com, member3@mydomain.com, member4@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus : 250 2.1.5 RESOLVER.GRP.Expanded; distribution list expanded

MessageId       : <0001>
EventId         : TRANSFER
Timestamp       : 14.12.2016 19:03:47
Recipients      : {member1@mydomain.com, member2@mydomain.com, member3@mydomain.com, member4@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus : {, , , }

MessageId       : <0001>
EventId         : DELIVER
Timestamp       : 14.12.2016 19:03:47
Recipients      : member1@mydomain.com
RecipientStatus :

MessageId       : <0001>
EventId         : DUPLICATEDELIVER
Timestamp       : 14.12.2016 19:03:48
Recipients      : member1@mydomain.com
RecipientStatus :
```

you can see the 250 2.1.5 RESOLVER.GRP.Expanded in the EXPAND event, and later the message is delivered just to member1, which is the only one user addressed in the e-mail out of the group. I believe the DUPLICATEDELIVER event is because member1 is addressed 2 times (inside the group and directly).

Finally, the e-mail was not delivered to the group members (and the sender didn't receive any NDR) and I don't understand why (it's a DistributionGroup-Universal, not DDG)

**UPDATE:**
I tried again (from a different external account) and now the e-mail was delivered first to member1, and after to all group members, except member1 because is a duplicate message. I believe this is the right behavior:

```
MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : RECEIVE
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : {member1@mydomain.com, group@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus :
MessageSubject  : test mail

MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : EXPAND
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : {member1@mydomain.com, member2@mydomain.com, member3@mydomain.com, member4@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus : 250 2.1.5 RESOLVER.GRP.Expanded; distribution list expanded
MessageSubject  : test mail

MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : TRANSFER
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : {member1@mydomain.com, member2@mydomain.com, member3@mydomain.com, member4@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus : {, , , }
MessageSubject  : test mail

MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : DELIVER
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : member1@mydomain.com
RecipientStatus :
MessageSubject  : test mail

MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : DELIVER
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : {member2@mydomain.com, member3@mydomain.com, member4@mydomain.com}
RecipientStatus :
MessageSubject  : test mail

MessageId       : <0002>
EventId         : DUPLICATEDELIVER
Timestamp       : 21.12.2016 7:05:02
Recipients      : member1@mydomain.com
RecipientStatus :
MessageSubject  : test mail
```

The original problem happened the last week, concretely from only one external address, and I see others emails to the group (from others external users) had been delivered to all group members. I tried now the combination of group + member1, how was in the problematic message for check if the noise come from the duplicate message, but I see there is delivered to everybody, so, I don't know what can be...

Comment: To be clear - if you send to the group alone, it doesn't work either? Is that with both internal and external senders?

Comment: @Sembee, the group has permission for receive external e-mails. I tried again from an external account and it's working. I don't know if the problem is just with a concretely sender. I update the post with more info, please, take a look.

Comment: If another external account works, then that would suggest the issue isn't with the group. You need to establish the pattern - it could be the one source.

Comment: Exactly, but what can be? The issue was with a client, so I can't be testing from his email. I tried with others external services (Gmail, Outlook) and look fine. During the weekend I updated and restarted the server... is the only thing come to my mind now

Comment: The usual problem is a cached entry - but if that was the case I wouldn't expect the email to be received by your server. If it is just a single client there is little you can do. Ask them to remove the cached entries. 

Depends if they are a regular sender or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow unauthenticated senders:

- In Exchange Management Console, right click the dist group and go to Properties.
- Click the Mail Flow Settings tab and click Message Delivery Restrictions.
- Click Properties.
- In the Message Delivery Restrictions Properties, uncheck the box "Require that all senders are authenticated"

Try it again.

Comment: Thank you Jarrod, please read my comment in the post. That was the first I controled :(